# collecting 'double' type data from arduino

Tags: python, c, arduino, atmega

I'm trying to send floating point data from arduino to python.The data is sent as 8 successive bytes of data (size of double) followed by newline character ('\n').How to collect these successive bytes and convert it to proper format at python end (system end)

```
void USART_transmitdouble(double* d)
{
    union Sharedblock
    {
        char part[sizeof(double)];
        double data;

    }my_block;
    my_block.data = *d;
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(double);++i)
    {
        USART_send(my_block.part[i]);
    }

    USART_send('\n');
}

int main()
{
    USART_init();
    double dble=5.5;
    while(1)
    {
       USART_transmitdouble(&dble);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

python code.Sure this wouldn't print the data in proper format but just want to show what i have tried.

```
import serial,time

my_port = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131',19200)
while 1:
    print my_port.readline(),
    time.sleep(0.15)
```

**Update**:

```
my_ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131',19200)

while 1:
    #a = raw_input('enter a value:')
    #my_ser.write(a)
    data = my_ser.read(5)
    f_data, = struct.unpack('<fx',data)
    print f_data
    #time.sleep(0.5)
```

Using `struct` module as shown in the above code is able to print float values. But,

50% of the time,the data is printed correctly.But if I mess with time.sleep() or stop the transmission and restart it,incorrect values are printed out.I guess the wrong set of 4 bytes are being **unpacked** in this case.Any idea on what we can do here??

Comment: You will definitely want to use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use it on floating point numbers. Maybe you should use integers instead or use your own binary format. Also, remember that you send the number in its raw binary representation, so it could definitely contain the ASCII code for a newline. You should use `read` instead of `readline` (and forget about the newline, you don't need it)

Comment: `struct.unpack` is carefully written to correctly unpack IEEE 754 floats received over the wire, regardless of how they are represented on the machine running Python. But it still expects to receive floats in the specified format, which the sending side should ensure to send. Prompted by your question, I looked at arduino's site, and was surprised to [learn](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double) that Arduino `double` is in fact single-width precision number, which means `struct` must be given the `f` format, not `d`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Arduino, a `double` is [the same as `float`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double), i.e. a little-endian [single-precision floating-point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_float) that occupies 4 bytes of memory. This means that you should read exactly 5 bytes, use the little-endian variant of the `f` format to unpack it, and ignore the trailing newline with `x`:

```
import struct
...

data = my_port.read(5)
num, = struct.unpack('<fx', data)
```

Note that you don't want to use `readline` because any byte of the representation of the floating-point number can be `'\n'`.

As Nikklas B. pointed out, you don't even need to bother with the newline at all, just send the 4 bytes and read as many from Python. In that case the format string will be `'<f'`.

Comment: though i'm using arduino,I din't use any of its libraries.My university don't want me to use arduino libraries.I'm using it as a simple atmega328p development board.I'm going to try this unpacking  now and report back.

Comment: And i tried both.Working great.I stopped sending newline character from arduino end and used '<f' format with my_port.read(4) to read 4 bytes of data.But the problem is python speed.I don't know if i can plot proper graphs at this speed.Anyway learnt something interesting today.Thank to u ;)

Comment: Try creating a `struct.Struct('<f')` object once and calling `unpack(data)` on that object. That will remove the need to recompile the `<f` format over and over again. Plus, if 
If you are transferring a large number of floats, it will be much more efficient to process them in bunches. For example, send 256 floats over the port and execute a single `unpack('<' + 'f' * 256)`.  If your target machine is little-endian, an even more efficient option is to use `numpy.frombuffer(data_received, dtype="float32")`, but this would be a good material for a different question.

Comment: I have a problem.50% of the time,the data is printed correctly.But if i mess with time.sleep() or stop the transmission and restart it,incorrect values are printed out.I guess the wrong set of 4 bytes are being unpacked in this case.Any idea on what we can do here??

Comment: I'd guess you need to implement some sort of synchronization — but you're likely to get much better responses if you formulate the problem as a separate question.

Comment: Ok.I'm going to do that.Thnx :)